# Can Ubuntu GNOME Remix be added to the supported derivatives page?

Tags: support

It looks like Gnome Remix is now an [officially supported Ubuntu derivative](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-gnome/2013-March/000035.html). See also [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/its-official-ubuntu-gnome-remix-joins-the-ubuntu-family).

Can someone update this page http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/derivatives or is this handled by Canonical once they get a custom Ubuntu Gnome page set up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Ask Ubuntu, and yes, Canonical will handle that themselves.

Comment: Not to mention it won't be supported until 13.04 is released.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to put this news out before we started getting Q's on remix.

Comment: @maggotbrain don't beat yourself over lack of enthusiasm, think you were just a tidy bit too fast, we will update Ask Ubuntu accordingly when the time comes, ubuntu.com pages will do the same.